# Selenium how to capture element screenshot?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am trying to access the "canvas" element, sin the screenshot.

I am running the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('canvas').screenshot("canvas.png")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('canvas').screenshot_as_png("chess.png")
```

[image]

Neither of the 2 above work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You were close enough. The *`<canvas>`* tag is within the *`<chess-board>`* tag.

---

### Solution

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) for the `<canvas>` element and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *TAG_NAME*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "canvas"))).screenshot_as_png("chess.png")
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "chess-board > canvas"))).screenshot_as_png("chess.png")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//chess-board/canvas"))).screenshot_as_png("chess.png")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: unfortunately, these do not work

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a class. Implement TestNG 'ITestListener'.
2)Call the method 'onTestFailure'.
3)Add the code to take a screenshot with this method.
4)Get the Test method name and take a screenshot with the test name. Then place it in the desired destination folder.